# How to stop ComboBox on subform from refreshing (requering) in MS Access 2010 and later

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010, refresh, ms-access-2007, subform

On the main form there's a linked subform with combobox on it. The underlying query of the combobox is rather complex and takes a few seconds to complete. In Access 2007 it is run only once when the form is opened. In Access 2010 every time I change the current record on the main form the combobox is refreshed and thus it takes awhile to move to the next record. Is there a setting in Access 2010 and later to change this behavior?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you can save the last value into variable.